# Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2 force me to use cmake 3.22.1 why?

Tags: gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working to upgrade AGP 7.1 to 7.4.2 in my project.
I have replaced AGP version to 7.4.2 and I got the following error:

```
[CXX1300] CMake '3.22.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
[CXX1301] - CMake '3.15.3' found in PATH did not satisfy requested version. 
[CXX1301] - CMake '3.10.2' found in SDK did not satisfy requested version.
[CXX1301] - CMake '3.18.1' found in SDK did not satisfy requested version.
```

I have checked every thing and I didn't find any issues in my project.
I didn't find any information about relations between AGP and CMake versions.

Please help me to understand why 3.18.1 CMake is not good any more.

Comment: Does your project have a [`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) in it?

Comment: No it doesn't. CMake minimum restriction would actual to AGP 7.1 but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I add `version = 3.18.1` to cmake section of build.gradle and build was satisfied.